# Cookie set and read not working in IE9 using asp.net code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer, cookies

IE 9 is setting `cookie` values in browser even after changing privacy settings. What is the next option to save cookies in IE?

see below my code.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
 If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
     If Not Request.Cookies("RememberMe") Is Nothing Then
            'this if condition is failing, it never executes and working in chrome.
     End If
End If

Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString()))
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private)
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache")
 End Sub

Protected Sub imgLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    If Page.IsValid() Then

        If Not user Is Nothing Then
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(strUserID, False)
            If (chkRememberMe.Checked) Then
                Helper.StoreRememberMe(strUserID, ddlCompany.SelectedItem.Text)
            ElseIf Not Request.Cookies("RememberMe") Is Nothing Then
                Helper.DeleteCookie("RememberMe")
            End If
            Session("userInfo") = user
            Response.Redirect("~/home.aspx")           
        End If
    End If    
End Sub

Public Shared Sub StoreRememberMe(ByVal username As String, ByVal company As String)
    Dim rememberMe As New HttpCookie("RememberMe")

    rememberMe.Values.Add("user", username)
    rememberMe.Values.Add("company", company)

    rememberMe.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30)
    'cookie Expires ;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendCookie(rememberMe)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have problem with setting cookies or removing them (title and post disagree).... In any case look at Fiddler trace (or any other HTTP traffic watcher) to see if you getting expected set cookie headers.

Comment: The thing is this code is working good Chrome and FireFox. Only in IE not working.